# rails active record persistance problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an orders object with a status field. I would like to retrieve all orders with status=1 (so I know what is being modified) and then update them to have a status=2. My code is as follows:

```
@new_orders=Order.where("status=1")

Order.where("status=1").update_all :status=>2
```

The problem is that @new_orders is not set until the view uses the variable. I am guessing this has to do with lazy loading. How do I get around this so I can display all records that have been modified?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `.all` or `.to_a` to the end of your relation:

```
@new_orders = Order.where(:status => 1).all
```